# When I try to use firebase in my flutter app it produces an error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

I wanted to use firebase in my flutter app, but when I try to reinstall the app after following the instructions that in the firebase console, but every time I do that same error pops up!

I tried by even creating a new project

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#6

this is the instructions I followed

I am coding in the VS-Code not in the Android Studio!

This is the error!

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\ACA Folder\Flutter Basics\google_demo_2\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\ACA Folder\Flutter Basics\google_demo_2\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
  Command: D:\ACA Folder\Flutter Basics\google_demo_2\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

After I ran the flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.737], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.2 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision 2d2a1ffec9 (3 weeks ago), 2019-09-06 18:39:49 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Achintha\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 39.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 191.8423
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.38.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Achintha\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.4.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

My app/build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.google_demo_2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Add your logs with command "flutter doctor -v". Also, show your both build.gradle files from android package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jose answer is partially correct, after upgrading the gradle version. I had to update the Kotlin version also to 1.3.41

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.41"
}
```

**It is advisable to use androidx (tick the following box)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You have to upgrade the gradle version (>= 3.3.0) in dependencies (/android/build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
}
```

Comment: This was part of an answer, after that, I had to update the Kotlin version to 1.3.41.